# UnsupportedClassVersionError that occurs only in JBoss 5.1

Tags: java, jboss, classloader, java-6

My application contains 3rd party jar (com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver-1.6.8.RELEASE.jar) 
that is compiled in Java6. I managed to use it on Tomcat 5.5 that runs Java5 but when I tried to deploy the same application on JBoss 5.1 - I get the error:

> [org.jboss.detailed.classloader.ClassLoaderManager]
>   (main) Unexpected error during load
>   of:testdata.SomeAnnotation
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   Bad version number in .class file

that I realized that happens not only to me. [as described here](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/EBR-622).

my questions: 
**1)** why is it possible to use this jar in web-servers such as tomcat but it still bothers Jboss 5.1 ? 
**2)** Why does Jboss class loader load the application's implementaiotn of Jweaver to be used for loading it framework and it doesn't use Jboss aspectJ implementation. Perhaps I should configure its class loading to be *parent-first* and it will solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is backwardly compatible, (a Java 5.0 jar can run on Java 6) but not forwardly compatible (A Java 6 jar cannot be used on Java 5.0)

You need to get a copy of the 3rd party Jar which is compiled for Java 5.0 or upgrade the version of Java to version 6 or later.

Comment: So how was I able to run the same Java6 classes while running my application on Tomcat? they are using the same Java JDK (1.5) - I think it is somehow related to JBoss class-loading mechanism

Comment: When you compile a jar in Java 6 you can specific a target of Java 5, however a Java 5.0 JVM will not load a Java 6 class regardless of how the classloader works. i.e. there is nothing the classloader can do about it without transcoding the classes as it loads them (I don't know of any classloader which does this) and it would be very unsafe to do so.

Answer (score 0):

On occasion, we have seen that students [HSG](http://www.hartmannsoftware.com) modify the jdk they use, reconfigure their environment to that end and still this exception continues to occur.  This can cause a considerable amount of confusion especially if they switched from the jdk1.6 to jdk1.5.  Almost always, the culprit is that one or several other versions of jboss are running and all incoming requests call on one of them (with the of the newer jars).  We always check to see which apps are running and kill/shutdown all other versions of jboss.